# Difference Between Empty Return Type for Method

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone suggest me what is the difference between

```
- (void)tabtwoAction:(id)sender;
```

and

```
- ()tabtwoAction:(id)sender;
```

with no return type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method return types default to `id`, so all of

```
- (id)foo;
- ()foo;
- foo;
```

are equivalent.

Comment: Haha :D You're the best :D And the fastest ;) ... definitely :D

Comment: Good info but the question wants to know the difference from these and a method with a `void` return type.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, the difference is... ...that `void` is not `id`!

Comment: @H2CO3 I know the difference but the OP doesn't. :) I was hinting that the OP may not realize that with `void` the method has no return value at all while the empty parentheses mean that the method must return an object since the empty parentheses mean the method has a return type of `id`.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think that it's the case. It's rather that OP may have though that `()` is equivalent to `(void)`, and this answer clearly points out that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

One "difference" is.. if you have the method...

```
- staySexy { [thanks gorgeous]; }
```

you will get a compiler error...

> error: returning `void` from a function with incompatible result type `id`

If the `(id)` is omitted (as has been discussed, it is actually just being *implied*)... the compiler will want (need? desire?) you to return *something* - aka an `Object`, or *at least* `nil` - not just `void`, or `return`!

```
- uglyMethod { return [loves it], nil; } // clang love you long time
```